# Center aligning image in div

Tags: css, image, firefox, alignment, center

### HTML

```
<div class="image-container">
   <img class="image" src="image.png">
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.image-container {
    width: 95px;
    height: 95px;
    background: #000000;

    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;

    -webkit-justify-content: center;       
    justify-content: center;
}

.image {
    max-width: 95px;
    max-height: 95px;
}
```

This works fine on Chrome and Safari but not in Firefox. It's filling up the whole div and aspect ratio is not maintained. How to make this work on Firefox?

### Chrome / Safari

[image]

### Firefox

[image]

Comment: set your images' width to 100% and height to auto usually does the trick

Comment: is working fine on Firefox for mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of your `.image` height stretch  the image. Change your css like this.

```
.image {
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.image {
 max-width: 95px;
}
```

or

```
.image {
 width: 100%;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.image{
position: relative;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it cross-browser you can use the following approach: Check working [JsFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/henser/57w1fctk/3/)

Only CSS required:

```
.image-container {
    width: 95px;
    height: 95px;
    background: #000000;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
}
```